# Play Json - Complex object creation

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create Json readers in my Play framework application (Scala). The problem is, part of my Json is a little funky, and requires further processing to retrieve the values. For example:

```
{  
  "field1":"value1",
  "field2":"value/1",
  "num2":2
}
```

with case classes:

```
case class Field1(text: String, fields: Field2)
case class Field2(text: String, num: Int, num2: Int)
```

Basically the `text` and `num` fields for `Field2` are derived from the value `value/1`, by splitting the text. Here's the splitter function:

```
def splitter(path: String, num2: Int): Field2 = {
  val split = path.split("\\")
  Field2(split(0), split(1).toInt, num2)
}
```

This is fairly straightforward, the actual splitter function is far more complex. Basically the only way to construct this object `Field2` is to pass a single string to a function that spits out the required object.

How do I go about creating a reader for `Field2` (and by extension for `Field1`)?

Here's what I have so far:

```
object Field1 {
    implicit val reader = (
        (__ \ "field1").read[String] and
        (__).read[Field2]
    ) (Field1.apply _)
}

object Field2 {
    implicit val reader = (
        splitter((__ \ "field2").read[String], (__ \ "num2"))
    ) // Obviously incorrect syntax + type mismatch, but this is roughly what I'm trying to accomplish.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the non-functional combinator syntax it becomes a little simpler I think:

```
object Field2 {
  implicit val reader = Reads[Field2] { json =>
    for {
      path <- (json \ "field2").validate[String]
      num2 <- (json \ "num2").validate[Int]
    } yield splitter(path, num2)
  }
}
```

Additionally if you want splitter to further validate the input have it return a `JsResult[Field2]` like this:

```
def splitter(path: String, num2: Int): JsResult[Field2] = {
  val split = path.split("\\")
  if (split.size != 2) {
    JsError(s"$path must be of the form: {field}\\{num}")
  } else {
    Try(Field2(split(0), split(1).toInt, num2)).map(JsSuccess(_)).getOrElse {
      JsError(s"${split(1)} is not a valid Int")
    }
  }
}
```

And then modify the reader:

```
object Field2 {
  implicit val reader = Reads[Field2] { json =>
    for {
      path <- (json \ "field2").validate[String]
      num2 <- (json \ "num2").validate[Int]
      field2 <- splitter(path, num2)
    } yield field2
  }
}
```

If you still prefer using the functional syntax and you don't mind the lack of validation that splitter does try this:

```
def splitter(path: String, num2: Int): Field2 = {
  val split = path.split("\\")
  Field2(split(0), split(1).toInt, num2)
}

implicit val reader = (
  (__ \ "field2").read[String] and
  (__ \ "num2").read[Int]
)(splitter _)
```

I'd recommend against this, it's unsafe (`split(1)` and `toInt` both might throw exceptions) and the functional syntax can have performance issues. See https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/08/29/speeding-up-restful-services-in-play-framework/.

Comment: This works beautifully. But is there no way to use the regular functional syntax? I've used that in other bits of my code, and I'd like to keep things consistent.

Comment: @Jeff The problem with the functional syntax is that you can't reference previous fields in order to compute things. Once you call apply, you can modify the generated Reader, but you need an intermediate type to track the data you've computed. In addition, under certain circumstances you might run into performance issues with the functional syntax: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/08/29/speeding-up-restful-services-in-play-framework/

Comment: @Jeff I've added an example that uses functional syntax.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need case classes, but you can also transform json for your needs with

```
 (__ \ "field2" \ "num2").json.copyFrom((__ \ "num2").json.pick) and
    (__ \ "field2").json.update(
      of[String].map { o =>
        val split = o.split("/")
        Json.obj(
          "text" -> split(0),
          "num" -> split(1).toInt
        )
      }
    )
  ).reduce andThen (__ \ "num2").json.prune

scala> j: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsSuccess({"field2":{"num2":2,"text":"value","num":1},"field1":"value1"},/num2)
```

and then you can use your `Reads[Field1]`

Comment: The case classes are an integral part of the system already designed. Also, the code I've provided is a small approximation of the actual code, which would be along the same lines, but much, much bigger, so transforming the json each time doesn't seem feasible.